# Proof Check: The cardinality of all monotonically increasing series of natural numbers.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Given an infinite series, $a_1a_2a_3\ldots$ define $F$, $F(a_1a_2a_3\ldots) = a_1\bmod(2)a_2\bmod(2)a_3\bmod(2)\ldots$

It's trivial to show that $F$ is onto the set of all infinite binary series, which has a cardinality of $\aleph_1$.

So the cardinality of the aforementioned set $\ge \aleph_1$.

Then again the set of all infinite binary sets is a subset of the set of all infinite series of natural numbers, therefore yielding a cardinality of $\le\aleph_1$.

All in all we get a cardinality of $\aleph_1$ by the Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem.

I feel like I might've made a mistake with $F$, but I'm not sure. Can anyone verify? Thanks for your time!

Comment: You seem to be assuming the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: I think you proved that the cardinality is $\geq 2^{\aleph_0}$ twice, although the set of all the infinite binary sequences is not a subset of the monotonically increasing sequences of natural numbers.

Comment: @Jay : I wouldn't leap to the conclusion that he's assuming the continuum hypothesis: some otherwise respectable mathematicians labor under the impression that $\aleph_1$ is _defined_ to be $2^{\aleph_0}$, the cardinality of the continuum.

Comment: @Michael: That's like saying that not knowing that theft is illegal means that you can take whatever you want from wherever you want.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : I have no idea how you drew that inference.  A mathematician who mistakenly thinks $\aleph_1$ is defined to be $2^{\aleph_0}$, might say something has cardinality $\aleph_1$ without assuming there are no cardinalities between that and $\aleph_0$, hence without assuming the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: @Michael: And a mathematician who doesn't know that $0$ is the unit of the additive group of the real numbers, might say that $0+0>0$. That doesn't mean that it's not a mistake. When something becomes engraved deep enough, to negate it requires an explicit setting of context (for example, even if $\Bbb R$ is used often for forcing posets, if one doesn't state this explicitly, it will still be considered as the set of real numbers).

Comment: I was under the impression that the $\aleph$'s were generally thought of as the cardinalities of the well-ordered sets.

Comment: PS: For the record: The fact that there are no cardinalities between $\aleph_0$ and $\aleph_1$ is provable without the axiom of choice and without the continuum hypothesis.  The relation $\aleph_1\le 2^{\aleph_0}$ is not provable in ZF but is provable in ZFC, i.e. ZF plus the axiom of choice.  The continuum hypothesis says there are no cardinalities between $\aleph_0$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$.  In ZFC, that is equivalent to $\aleph_1=2^{\aleph_0}$.  In ZF, it is possible that $\aleph_1$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$ are incomparable even if the continuum hypothesis is true.

Comment: @Jay : That is correct.  $\aleph_1$ is the cardinality of the set of all countable ordinals.  Has someone other than the original poster said anything conflicting with that?

Comment: @AsafKaragila : I did NOT say that what the original poster said was not a mistake.  What I said was that one cannot infer that the original poster is assuming the continuum hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

Your gravest mistake is that $\aleph_1$ is **NOT** the cardinality of the continuum (well, at least not in general). We define $\aleph_1$ to be the least uncountable cardinal, whereas $2^{\aleph_0}$ is just uncountable. It is consistent with the axioms of set theory that they are equal, and it is consistent that they are not.

The $F$ that you define is fine, and it is indeed a surjection from the set of monotonically increasing *sequences* onto the set of binary sequences. This establishes, as you point out that the cardinality of the set that you are interested in is at least $2^{\aleph_0}$.

However the second part is not well-written. You provide a second argument as to why the cardinality is at least $2^{\aleph_0}$ rather than providing an argument that it is **at most** $2^{\aleph_0}$ (which will then imply equality).

**HINT:** Every sequence of natural numbers is in fact a function $f\colon\Bbb{N\to N}$. Note that such function $f$ is a subset of $\Bbb{N\times N}$. How many subsets does this product have?

Comment: Thanks for this, your hint really clears things up. If I change every aleph1 in my proof to C, the cardinaltiy of R, will my proof be correct?

Comment: Why do I need a second argument that the cardinality is at least C?

Comment: You don't *need* a second one, you *have* a second one. You proved the same direction in two different ways. One of them is quite sketchy as it is.

Comment: Ahh, I've made a few mistakes. This:" Then again the set of all infinite binary sets is a subset of the set of all infinite series of natural numbers, therefore yielding a cardinality of ≤ℵ1. " Should've been: "Then again the set of all infinite monotonically increasing series of natural numbers is a subset of the set of all infinite series of natural numbers, therefore yielding a cardinality of ≤ℵ1."

Comment: I also misread your answer. Is this revised version correct?

Comment: Mark, yes, up to the needed modification of $\aleph_1$ to $2^{\aleph_0}$.